# What storage policy is being used in the bucket of boost::intrusive::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, hashmap, unordered-map

I understand that boost buckets internally are implemented as liked lists, right?  At least according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/unordered/buckets.html it seems like it.

My question is, what is the order of elements in these buckets? If they are unordered, is there any way to enforce MRU (most recently used) or some other move-to-front heuristic onto items order in these buckets?

Edit: I understand arguments against enforcing MRU inside buckets. But in my specific case I know, that enforcing MRU [or even having last-in-first-served] would outperform having smaller load factor. Question is, what is the order? Is there a simple way to enforce at least last-inserted-first-out&served.

Comment: The goal is for each of the lists to be small, and as such, an MRU would slow it down.  Also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/unordered/rationale.html implies there's special iterator requirements that prevent them from reordering nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buckets are unsorted.  There are compelling reasons why the buckets are unsorted.  While I'm sure you're aware of this, I'll enumerate a couple to help future visitors of the site.

1. A hash map-type data structurre should not invalidate iterators unless an insertion results in a rehash
2. In order to preserve fast lookup, the buckets should be small; ideally, each bucket should have just one element in them.

Enforcing MRU ordering of the buckets seems, to my eyes, to be against the whole idea of a hash map-type structure in the first place.  The idea is to keep the buckets small so that, on average, the first item in the bucket is the one you're actually looking for.

Because of this, I doubt there's any built-in way to enforce MRU ordering within the buckets.  I'd recommend tuning your hashing algorithm instead, maybe turning down your max load factor.

Comment: My accesses to the hash table have strong MRU and locality statistics. So I would really prefer having MRU-friendly hashset.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may have to create your own then.  I know of no hash map implementations that provide what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know what order is being used there internally? LIFO? or FIFO?  Where can I look it up? I tried bucket_type, bucket_traits, but the relevant file eludes me...

Comment: I can't say for certain, but since a hash map insert should never invalidate iterators unless there is a rehash, I'd guess they must be doing a `push_back`

Comment: 2 John. Thanks to your comments and excellent advice. I'll put an accept on your answer in couple of days, 50/50 with mine...

Answer (score 0):

After some hacking, answering my own question.

Boost buckets implementation is in the: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp.

Although this is implementation specific and may change at any time, currently, for intrusive unordered_set, bucket traversal [in .find()] *starts from items inserted last*.

For example, if you would declare an unordered_set with 1000 buckets:

```
class A : public unordered_set_base_hook<> { ... }
unordered_set<A>::bucket_type buckets[1000];
unordered_set<A> a(unordered_set<A>::bucket_traits(buckets, 1000));
```

and insert 10000 randomly sampled items [ridiculously high load factor 10], *items inserted in the end would have faster [by order of magnitude] access [find] time*.